# Intalio Ajax Forms pointing to localhost

Tags: eclipse, business-process-management

Anyone working with Intalio|BPMS?

I'm trying to implement a process using the Comunity Edition, and I'm having a problem I can't seem to solve.

The process has an AJAX Form and if I go to ui-fw in the server using localhost everything works, but if I try to access the server remotely using the url it doesn't.

The iframe for the AJAX Form is pointing to localhost and not the url.

From the very bad foruns at Intalio, I've checked /tried:

- deploy from the designer using the url
- finding every mention of localhost in the process deploy dir, and also in the var/conf

Still no luck.

Any ideas anyone??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ricardo, we spent some time fixing the forums. Wanna take a look and let me know if you like the changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo, IIRC the form is deployed according to the settings you use in the deployment manifest. I believe you can also set an other host name in the deployment manifest to deploy to localhost, but declare a different host name for the form and processes.